# Exception in showing dialog

Tags: android, android-widget

I am using custom layout for my dialog. This is a method in util java(not an activity).

```
public void showLoadingProgress(String msg){
    Log.d("EditorUtil", "show loading progress"+progressDialog);//No i18n
    if(progressDialog!=null && progressDialog.isShowing()){
        TextView message = (TextView)progressDialog.findViewById(R.id.progressmsg);
        message.setText(msg);
        return;
    }

Context context = EditorActivity.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
progressDialog = new Dialog(EditorActivity.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
progressDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
progressDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
progressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.customprogress);

TextView message = (TextView)progressDialog.findViewById(R.id.progressmsg);
message.setText(msg);

progressDialog.show();
Log.d("",progressDialog.isShowing()+""); //No i18n
```

}

I got an Exception like

```
03-26 11:23:41.672: W/dalvikvm(8034): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c2d930)
03-26 11:23:41.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8034): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 11:23:41.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8034): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-26 11:23:41.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8034):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3597)
03-26 11:23:41.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8034):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
03-26 11:23:41.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8034):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
03-26 11:23:41.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8034):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-26 11:23:41.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8034):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-26 11:23:41.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8034):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-26 11:23:41.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8034):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-26 11:23:41.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8034):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 11:23:41.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8034):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-26 11:23:41.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8034):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-26 11:23:41.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8034):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-26 11:23:41.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8034):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-26 11:23:41.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8034): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-26 11:23:41.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8034):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 11:23:41.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8034):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-26 11:23:41.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8034):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3592)
03-26 11:23:41.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8034):     ... 11 more
03-26 11:23:41.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8034): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
03-26 11:23:41.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8034):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:571)
03-26 11:23:41.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8034):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:246)
03-26 11:23:41.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8034):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
03-26 11:23:41.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8034):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281
```

Comment: have u tried `EditorActivity.getActivity()` instead of `EditorActivity.getActivity().getApplicationContext()`

Answer (score 1):

for showing `progressDialog` from non Activity call you will need to pass Current Activity Context instead of Application Context to Dialog Constructor. you can pass Activity context to  showLoadingProgress by adding one more parameter:

```
public void showLoadingProgress(String msg,Context context){

 //.....
progressDialog = new Dialog(context);
 //.....

}
```

now pass `EditorActivity.getActivity()` as second parameter to `showLoadingProgress` method